# i can't presist data in kubernetes volumes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, persistent-volumes, mounted-volumes

i have an application that record live traffic and replay them.

https://github.com/buger/goreplay

it is a simple app to use, but when i tried to use it with kubernetes i get a problem with persisting data in volumes.

i want to do this :

- in pod number one i use the goreplay container and other container that just have a simple python server... the job is the goreplay will listen to the requests coming from outside to the server and save them to a file , this is the deployment file :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: goreplay-deployment
  labels:
        app: goreplay-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: goreplay-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: goreplay-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: goreplay
        image: feiznouri/goreplay:2.0
        args:
          - "--input-raw"
          - ":3000"
          - "--output-file=requests_docker.gor"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: data
            mountPath: /var/lib/goreplay
      - name: myserver
        image: feiznouri/python-server:1.1
        args:
          - "3000"
        ports:
        - name: server-port
          containerPort: 3000
      volumes:
      - name: data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: goreplay-claim
```

normally this will create the file.

the prblem is that when i delete the deployment, and create one that it's job is to read the file and forward the saving request to a server, it can't find the file , clearly i am using the volumes wrong , this is the second deployment that suppose to find and read the file :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: goreplay-deployment
  labels:
        app: goreplay-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: goreplay-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: goreplay-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: goreplay
        image: feiznouri/goreplay:2.0
        args:
          - "--input-file"
          - "requests_docker_0.gor"
          - "--output-http=http://localhost:3000"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: data
            mountPath: /var/lib/goreplay
      - name: myserver
        image: feiznouri/python-server:1.1
        args:
          - "3000"
        ports:
        - name: server-port
          containerPort: 3000
      volumes:
      - name: data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: goreplay-claim
```

PS: this is the yaml file for the persistent volume :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: goreplay-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: custum
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

and this the file for the storage class :

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: custom
provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

and this for the persistent volume claim :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: goreplay-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: custum
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Mi
```

how can i make this work and find and use the first file that i created in the second pod !

thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure you're not deleting and recreating the persistent volume?

Comment: If the two containers don't get scheduled on the same node, the `hostPath` will refer to different places.  Unfortunately, most of the volume types that are relatively easy to get don't support ReadWriteMany access mode.  Can you restructure this to not need shared files at all, maybe by one service sending the other data through an HTTP request or a message queue?

Comment: @DanielFarrell no the persistent volume is on since two days

Comment: @DavidMaze i'm not sure what you're proposing but i just want to say that i'm using minikube , so i don't think that there are more than one node , right ?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes i can directly forword the request from one to the other and i manage to do it , but the app offers this feature of saving in files then use it , and i just wanted to apply it in kubernetes , but it seems that the volumes thing is a bit complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replicated it and it looks like the volumes are fine.

What is not fine, is how you pass file paths to goreplay.

Here is what I did:

```
kubectl exec -it goreplay-deployment-899c49f95-7qdh4 -c goreplay sh
/home/goreplay # ps auxwf
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 ./gor --input-raw :3000 --output-file=requests_docker.gor
   36 root      0:00 sh
   42 root      0:00 ps auxwf
/home/goreplay # ls /proc/1/cwd -l
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Feb 19 09:44 /proc/1/cwd -> /home/goreplay
```

Let me explain what you see here. I execed into goreplay container and checked the PID of goreplay process (PID=1). Next, I checked what is this process's current working directory by checking the `/proc/1/cwd` symlink. As you see it's symlinked to `/home/goreplay`.

What does it tell us?

It tells us that `--output-file=requests_docker.gor` is making goreplay to save the file in `/home/goreplay/requests_docker.gor` (since you are specifying path relative to process's current working dir instead of using absolute path pointing to volume). It should be set to:

```
--output-file=/var/lib/gorepath/requests_docker.gor
```

since it's the directory where the volume is mounted.

---

Same applies to the second deployment. You should specify:

```
--input-file=/var/lib/goreplay/requests_docker_0.gor`
```

so that it reads from the volume and not from the pod's home directory (`/home/goreplay`).

---

Change it and it should work.

Comment: great perfect answer, thank you it worked ! :)

Comment: can you plz reference me to how to debug the way you just did ? any docs on this will help